# How to identify the customer on a server-sent event for Apple subscriptions?

Tags: ios, app-store, server-sent-events

Implementing subscriptions on an `iOS` app means we want to handle [SSEs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/notification_type) in case of subscription status change, as to manage the user's rights inside the service.

The Apple documentation doesn't show an explicit customer GUID.

They provide, in each SSE's payload, receipts, e.g. [the latest one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/latest_receipt_info).

**The question is: how can an API server uniquely identify customers?**

Should the API server keep track of *every* receipt, in an inheritance way?
I.e. should the API persist every receipt, and a link to the previous receipt, up to the first
one that was emitted (which can be linked to a customer through the iOS app the user used to initiate its subscription), and re-trace this history on every SSE?

Per [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14136), the `applicationUsername` service-side UUID (used by apple, for "irregular activity checking") isn't a solution, as it isn't provided in receipts or SSEs. The thread hints that using the transaction IDs is still the best way to identify a SSE, as it is ultimately tied to a user, and it is up to the service to keep track of transactions made by the user on the Apple platform for the given service.

**Isn't there an easier, more direct, way, to establish the relationship between a SSE, its apple customer, and the service's user?**

Comment: I just found out [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/original_transaction_id), which indicates *as an example* that it can be used to identify renewals for a given subscription, so for a given user. I'm gonna try to dig into that futher on, and if that appears to be, indeed, true, then I'll post an answer with my findings and what I concluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for a while and asking around, I reached the following conclusion:

There is only one way to tie a transaction event to a user, and that is by the
restoration mechanism one has to implement on their application.

For this reason, you need to at least keep track of *original* transaction IDs,
so when the restoration mechanism is triggered on your app, you can check the
currently logged user on your app, and call your back-end with the logged user,
and a list of original transaction IDs.

Usually, when a user subscribes, it is mainly done from within your app, so you
can do this link in a trivial way.

But, because you can "re-subscribe" from the AppStore after a while, without
going through your app, Apple may send a SSE to your back-end which would contain
a new (hence unknown) original transaction ID, since this new subscription is
has a new transaction.

---

In short,

- You need to keep *at least* a DB of original transaction IDs you receive as SSEs
- You need to implement the restoration mechanism as to contact your server every
  time the app starts, with the list of transaction IDs / original transaction IDs Apple gives you
- You need to accept having transactions stored in your backend without a link
  to a user (because the user may have re-subscribed without launching the app yet)